# Select [COLUMN_NAME] AS, self referencing table

Tags: postgresql, tree, hierarchy, self-referencing-table

The following is my function **get_reportees** performed on the self referencing table **emp_tabref1**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_reportees4(IN id integer)
RETURNS TABLE(e_id integer, e_name character varying, e_manager integer, e_man_name character varying) AS
$$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY
WITH RECURSIVE manger_hierarchy(e_id, e_name, m_id, m_name) AS 
(
SELECT e.emp_id, e.emp_name, e.mgr_id, e.emp_name AS man_name
FROM emp_tabref1 e WHERE e.emp_id = id
UNION
SELECT rp.emp_id, rp.emp_name, rp.mgr_id, rp.emp_name AS man_name
FROM manger_hierarchy mh INNER JOIN emp_tabref1 rp ON mh.e_id = rp.mgr_id
)
SELECT * from manger_hierarchy;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Table structure of emp_tabref1:

```
CREATE TABLE **emp_tabref1**
(
emp_id integer NOT NULL,
emp_name character varying(50) NOT NULL,
mgr_id integer,
CONSTRAINT emp_tabref_pkey PRIMARY KEY (emp_id),
CONSTRAINT emp_tabref_mgr_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (mgr_id)
  REFERENCES emp_tabref (emp_id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

What I want returned is the hierarchy (both above and below) of the id that we are passing which will have the emp_name, emp_id, mgr_id and **mgr_name**.

But my function is returning like this:

```
select * from get_reportees4(9)

   e_id e_name  e_manager e_man_name
1    9  "Emp9"  10        "Emp9"
2    5  "Emp5"  9         "Emp5"
3    6  "Emp6"  9         "Emp6"
```

where my expected output is

```
       e_id e_name  e_manager e_man_name
1    9  "Emp9"        10        "Emp10"
2    5  "Emp5"         9        "Emp9"
3    6  "Emp6"         9        "Emp9"
```

The function should return the manager name and not the employee name. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution! By creating a new join between the temporary manger_hierarchy table and the emp_tabref1 table using mgr_id and emp_id

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_reportees4(IN id integer)
RETURNS TABLE(e_id integer, e_name character varying, e_manager integer, e_man_name character varying) AS
$$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY 
WITH RECURSIVE manger_hierarchy(e_id, e_name, m_id, m_name) AS 
(
SELECT e.emp_id, e.emp_name, e.mgr_id, e.emp_name AS man_name
FROM emp_tabref1 e WHERE e.emp_id = id
UNION
SELECT rp.emp_id, rp.emp_name, rp.mgr_id, rp.emp_name AS man_name
FROM manger_hierarchy mh INNER JOIN emp_tabref1 rp ON mh.e_id = rp.mgr_id 
)
SELECT manger_hierarchy.e_id, manger_hierarchy.e_name, manger_hierarchy.m_id, emp_tabref1.emp_name 
FROM manger_hierarchy LEFT JOIN emp_tabref1 ON manger_hierarchy.m_id = emp_tabref1.emp_id;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

**SELECT manger_hierarchy.e_id, manger_hierarchy.e_name, manger_hierarchy.m_id, emp_tabref1.emp_name 
    FROM manger_hierarchy LEFT JOIN emp_tabref1 ON manger_hierarchy.m_id = emp_tabref1.emp_id;**